# Entity Framework not completing object graph of linked child objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using this method to create a set of child objects for each "Customer" after the Customer is created and saved:

```
public List<ListTnc> GetNewTncs()
{
    List <ListTnc> listTncs = new List<ListTnc>();
    List<SuppressionVariant> variants = SuppressionVariants.ToList();

    foreach (var suppressionList in SuppressionLists.Where(sl => sl.RequireTnc))
    {
        if (variants.Any(d => d.ListName == suppressionList.ListName))
        {
            listTncs.Add(new ListTnc { SuppressionListId = variants.Where(d => d.ListName == suppressionList.ListName)
                            .FirstOrDefault().SuppressionListId });
        }
        else
        {
            listTncs.Add(new ListTnc { SuppressionListId = suppressionList.SuppressionListId });
        }
    }

    return listTncs;
}
```

This works fine, and returns the expected data - a list of `ListTnc` objects which only have their SuppressionListId populated. There's no difference I can see between objects that were added in the top or bottom half of the `if` statement. I invoke it like this:

```
if (model.ListTncs == null || model.ListTncs.Count == 0)
{
    model.ListTncs = GetNewTncs();
}
```

And again that seems fine. What's odd is that when I save it:

```
Rep.UpdateAndSave(model);

public void UpdateAndSave<T>(T updateItem) where T : class
{
    Update(updateItem);
    SaveChanges();
}
```

At this point the data saves in the DB and I can query it, linked to the `Customer` and `SuppressionList` tables using `JOIN` statements, and it looks fine - all the data is as expected.

However in the C# code, any `ListTnc` objects that were populated in the `else` statement have a full object graph, but objects that were populated in the `if` statement lack their linked SuppressionList object. This causes the View to error.

If I reload the page, it fetches the full object graph and everything is fine. Why is the Save statement not causing all the child objects to populate their object graph?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it seems the correct Id isn't enough for EF to pick up the link between the objects. It has to be the correct Id *from the correct object*.

I fixed it by doing this:

```
public List<ListTnc> GetNewTncs()
{
    List <ListTnc> listTncs = new List<ListTnc>();
    List<SuppressionVariant> variants = SuppressionVariants.Include("SuppressionList).ToList();

    foreach (var suppressionList in SuppressionLists.Where(sl => sl.RequireTnc))
    {
        if (variants.Any(d => d.ListName == suppressionList.ListName))
        {
            listTncs.Add(new ListTnc { SuppressionListId = variants.Where(d => d.ListName == suppressionList.ListName)
                            .FirstOrDefault().SuppressionList.SuppressionListId });
        }
        else
        {
            listTncs.Add(new ListTnc { SuppressionListId = suppressionList.SuppressionListId });
        }
    }

    return listTncs;
}
```

So now the `SuppressionListId` is coming from the actual `SuppressionList` object, rather than the linked `SuppressionVariant`, and EF recognises the link and populates the child.